# i want to pass a model view in .load function of ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

in view of create milestone.. I have following `ajax` success function.

```
success: function (data) {
  $('#projectsummay').load("/Projects/ProjectSummary/", { project: data });

}
```

i m creating a milestone.
in milestone controller.

```
public JsonResult Create(Milestone milestone, string t) 
{ 
//...... 
var prj = db.Projects.Single(x => x.Id == milestone.ProjectId);
return Json(prj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

getting this prj in data. and sending it to the project controller

```
public ActionResult ProjectSummary(Project project)
{
//......
return PartialView(project);
}
```

this projectsummary function is hit but the object (project) is null.

Comment: Why in the world are you making and ajax call to return data, and then making another ajax call to send it straight back to the controller again to return a view? You need to show the relevant code including your controller methods and what `data` is (this wont work unless `data` is a simple value type or string)

Comment: In data pass a json string - it is lighter and more preferred.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i dont want to reload the whole page i want to return an updated partial view so that is why i m sending it back to controller

Comment: But why are you making 2 ajax calls? The first ones sends `data` from the controller` and the then you immediately send it back to the controller again and then return a partial view. And again SHOW THE CODE!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke i m creating a milestone on a project view.

in milestone controller..
public JsonResult Create(Milestone milestone, string  t)
        {
            //......
                var prj = db.Projects.Single(x => x.Id == milestone.ProjectId);
                
               
                
             
                return Json(prj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
getting this prj in data.. and sending it to the project controller

Comment: Edit your question and show ALL the relevant code - the full code for the ajax, and both controller methods (not in comments)

Comment: @StephenMuecke check now

Comment: Then it needs to be `$('#projectsummay').load("/Projects/ProjectSummary/", data);`, but again, why are you making 2 ajax calls instead of having your `Create()` method return the partial view and just use `$('#projectsummay').html(data);`?

Comment: because i have to load different data in different div's its only one of them.
its not working i have already tried this

Comment: Sorry, but that is not making sense (and its not what your code you have shown us does. Show the complete ajax code, and show you model for `Project` (it would only work if it contained only simple properties)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass this in load function and it should look like as follows in controller.

```
public ActionResult ProjectSummary(YourDataModel project)
{
    //...........
}
```

**Update**

```
$('#projectsummay').load("/Projects/ProjectSummary/", data);
```

Comment: i m passing it in controller but there all the values are null i.e. model is null

Comment: Are you passing same model which you have returned for `data`. You need to return like `return Json(objmodel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`.@MuhammadAli

Comment: Please elaborate on how to pass a Model as a parameter in ajax function to the controller..

Comment: yes i m passing same model which i have returned in data. same as you have mention. projectsummary method is hit but the object of project is null